# DbContext many to many relation not updating in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I'm encountering a curious little error with my DbContext.

In the GET portion of my edit action, I pull the model this way, which is then passed to the view:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id) {
    // ........

    model.Event = await db.Events
        .Include(x => x.EventAttendees)
        .Include(x => x.DiscussionTopics)
        .Include(x => x.ProviderFeedback)
        .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    // ........
}
```

The POST portion is where the occur is occuring.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EventViewModel model) {
    // ........

    // I had to add this line to get this piece to save
    db.Entry(model.Event.ProviderFeedback).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(model.Event).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    // ........

}
```

The main body of the Event saves, and the Provider Feedback (which is a one-to-one relationship). However, Attendees and DiscussionTopics (many to many) do not save. In the Create view, these items add and are saved to the database correctly. However, the Edit method of the controller will not update either of these.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you load your many to many relationship's? before updating them. Like db.Events.Include(x => x.EventAttendees)
        .Include(x => x.DiscussionTopics)
        .Include(x => x.ProviderFeedback)
        .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == model.Event.EventId); In you post method?

Comment: No I don't. Wouldn't reloading it overwrite the changes that were made to the model?